# Javascript regex: How to modify the code to single out numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, regex

I want to use regex to single out english word, special characters and numbers. I got the code:

```
var nregex=/[^\u0000-\u007F]|[\u0000-\u0008\u0011\u0012\u0014-\u0019\u0021-\u007F]+/g;
```

The code above does single out english words and some special characters but fails to single out numbers. It treats "12345" as one object, while I'm looking for [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Actually it **does** match numbers. What's the problem?

Comment: It treats "12345" as one object, while I'm looking for [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Try [`([^\u0000-\u007F]+)|([\u0000-\u0008\u0011\u0012\u0014-\u0019\u0021-\u0029\u0040-\u007F]+)|(\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/gM9cA6/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var results = str.match(/[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]/g);
```

Or maybe you're looking to isolate words, digits, and special chars? In which case:

```
var words = str.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
var digits = str.match([0-9]/g);
var specialChars = str.match(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\d|[^\u0000-\u007F]|[\u0000-\u0008\u0011\u0012\u0014-\u0019\u0021-\u002F\u003A-\u007F]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]